# Why are my Rails-like callbacks around Ruby methods not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Callbacks
  def self.before_actions
    @before_actions ||= []
  end

  def self.before_action(callback)
    before_actions << callback
  end

  def self.inherited(child_class)
    before_actions.each { |f| child_class.before_actions << f }
    after_actions.each { |f| child_class.after_actions << f }
  end

  def execute(action)
    self.class.before_actions.each { |callback| send(callback) }
    send(action)
    self.class.after_actions.each { |callback| send(callback) }
  end
end

class Test < Callbacks
  before_action :hello

  def heraks
    puts "heraks"
  end

  private

  def hello
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

Test.new.execute(:heraks)
```

This works, but if I write `@before_actions = []`, without `||`, then it doesn't work.

If I change how callbacks are stored to this:

```
@@callbacks = []
def self.before_actions(action)
  @@callbacks << action
end
```

it works.

I used byebug and checked that `Test.before_actions == []` and `before_action :hello` don't add to the array.

What is the difference between them? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a class instance variable (`@before_actions`) and `self.before_actions` uses `||=` your code works; fine.

When `self.before_actions` uses `=` instead of `||=` your code fails because every time you call `before_actions` it resets `@before_actions` to `[]`. No callback will stay defined long enough to do anything.

Your version of your code that uses a class variable (`@@callbacks`) sort of works because you're initializing `@@callbacks` only once outside the accessor. However, you'll have problems as soon as you have two subclasses of `Callbacks`: `Callbacks` and its subclasses will all share the same `@@callbacks`, so you won't be able to have different subclasses with different callbacks.